# codeigniter Dynamic baseurl to access app via lan break css fontfamily

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, codeigniter

Problem was i wanted to access my codeigniter app from other devices on the wifi network, i noticed all css breaks; so i edited my base_url to

config.php

```
$config['base_url']= "http://".gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."/ehit";
```

and my .htaccess is as

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

now everything loads correctly when i open my app from other devices like

`http://192.168.1.61/ehit` except for fontsAwsome.

html source

```
<!-- Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/ehit/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/ehit/assets/css/googlefont.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/ehit/assets/css/font-awesome.css">
```

all loads correctly by fontfamily is not defined. inside font-awesome.css i find

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

so may be the `url('..` is the problem; is there  a way to fix it ?

i debug and find that the url is correctly still font-family FontAwesome is not there

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1/ehit/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: 127.0.0.1' -H 'Origin: http://localhost' -H 'Referer: http://127.0.0.1/ehit/assets/css/font-awesome.css' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0'
```

so where is the problem ?

**EDIT**

Problem solved when i changed `$config` to

```
//$config['base_url']= "http://".gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."/ehit"; //old
$root=(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://").$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root.= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;
```

so what was the problem ?

Comment: Same problem, but I only change the config.php. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To application/config/config.php Change localhost to your IP Address
Visit all site on your IP Address

Example:
 $config['base_url']    = 'http://192.168.xx.xx/codeigniter-project/';

```
PC  192.168.xx.xx/codeigniter-project<br>

Mobile 192.168.xx.xx/codeigniter-project<br>



tablet  192.168.xx.xx/codeigniter-project<br>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow .woff files in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|woff|eot|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
```

This could be a possible cause.